# php detect image orientation "without exif"?

Tags: php, image-processing, detection, exif, exiftool

my question is what to do to detect image orientation when exif data don't exist or don't have rotation value.

Example : photo from mobile phone

```
<?php echo exec('exiftool -Orientation file 2>&1'); 
// MOBILE -> returns -> Orientation : Rotate 90 CW
// DSLR -> returns -> empty ?>
```

When I try this

```
echo exif_read_data($multimedia_newPATH)['Orientation']
// Mobile Phone -> 6
// DSLR -> value 1 (horizontal and/or vertical) gives same 1
```

**EDIT** Many DSLR write orientation 1 (normal) for both when camera is horizon or vertical, so a normal php script would "think" there is no rotation to perform.

so is there a orientation algorithm or orientation recognition script ????
(face recognition exists, but is there orientation recognition ?)

*** note ; exiftool is in perl modules (Image::ExifTool) in WHM...

Comment: Which image format is used? JPEG?

Comment: @odan yes jpg, Many DSLR write orientation 1 (normal) for both when cam horizon or vertical, so a normal php script would "think" there is no rotation to perform...

Comment: Sorry for going off topic, but might I ask what camera you are using that does this?  I've never heard of a DSLR that didn't have a sensor to keep track of the orientation.  Even old point and click cameras I've used have the ability to detect the orientation.

Comment: "recognition" of orientation is far easier than of faces: you just check the width against the height of the image. If width is larger, the it's landscape. Otherwise, it's portrait (unless they're equal, of course).

Comment: @l-scott-johnson the camera I tested (canon rebel 7D) does 6000x4000 in both cases horizontal AND vertical and orientation=1 in both cases as well, so how can the php script know if it's landscape ?

Answer (score 1):

RotNet is a neural-network-based algorithm that does automatic image orientation and rotation.

Source: https://github.com/d4nst/RotNet

Description: https://d4nst.github.io/2017/01/12/image-orientation/

[Google has also done some work](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1530000/1526822/p841-gossweiler.pdf?ip=129.252.15.128&id=1526822&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=A79D83B43E50B5B8%2EDAB8E865A120F1C3%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&__acm__=1563192988_283a1ae950b06ef18fc8d5d6dd5857b9) on this problem, combining neural nets with using Captcha to crowd source the "difficult" cases.

Comment: Cool, thanks ;) the article looks good, I'll do some tests on it